# How can I extract a query string from these logs?

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of lines in a log file where I need to extract only the query string part. I have identified these pattern:

```
/path/optin.html?e=somebase64string&l=somedifferentbase64string HTTP...
"/path/optin.html?e=somebase64string%3D&l=somedifferentbase64string" "browser info"...
"/path/optin.html?" "browser info"...
```

Some notes:

- Sometimes path and query string are enclosed in double quotes
- Sometimes there's no query string at all, obviously the ones with no query string are to be discarded.
- Sometimes the base64 string was url encoded, so the ending "=" part comes as "%3D" instead. I don't think this has affected my script but I'd thought I'd note it also.

So, I was able to correctly extract - hopefully - all of the lines that follow the first pattern above, but the others I'm having some trouble with.

This is the pattern I'm trying with:

```
$pattern = '/html\?(.*)\s*HTTP/';
```

then I run a *preg_match* against the log line.

Anyone can help me out with a better regex pattern?

I need to grab this part off the log lines:

e=somebase64string&l=somedifferentbase64string

Thanks

Comment: what is your expected outcome? please add that too in your question

Comment: Did you check `parse_url()`? Explode with a space, and parse the first element.

Comment: I tried parse_str to convert the extracted query string into an array and manipulate that way, I didn't think of parse_url, so I will have to test it out, thanks

Comment: parse_url() didn't work, the lines are way more complex than the samples I used above, and the query string gets extracted with some other extra text that I don't need, but that was a nice suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern like `~\?([^\s.]*)~` to match everything after a `?` until you reach a whitespace character (assuming a rule that "URLs will never have spaces in them [that aren't `%20`]):

```
$pattern = '~\?([^\s.]*)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $logs, $output);
```

Then trim off any quotes (e.g. in your last example):

```
$output = array_map(function($var) { return rtrim($var, '"'); }, $output[1]);
```

Giving you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => e=somebase64string&l=somedifferentbase64string
    [1] => e=somebase64string%3D&l=somedifferentbase64string
    [2] => 
)
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/513325)

Comment: this one might work, I'm currently testing it out, thanks

Comment: I modified the pattern a bit to fit my needs: ~optin.html\?([^\s.]*)~ but this was the correct answer, thanks!